# WordPress and jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, wordpress, jquery-ui

I like to know if there is already installed in WordPress the jQuery UI for the administration panel.

If not then I have to load it.

If is loaded how can I use it ?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would include a script reference to jQueryUI in the head tag of your 'header.php' template as then you have more control over which version and where that version is obtained from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include jquery by including the following in header.php

```
<?php 
wp_enqueue_script("jquery");
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
php wp_head(); 
?>
```

[Source](http://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/)

Comment: This is not what I want. I know how to include jQuery. Just I asking if in admin panel already exists the backend of the wordpress or If I have to manual included

Comment: for all followers - jquery exists in wordpress... Also. you should not include in your head. Additional information here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script